# How to specify package location in cmake file?

Tags: c++, cmake, catkin, g2o

I have two versions of the same library ([g2o](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o)) on my Ubuntu 18.04 pc. One is built with `catkin_make` in a ROS workspace (/home/riccardo/catkin_ws/src/g2o).
The other one is in the directory of the project I'm trying to build (/home/myproject/g2o).
As I said, I'm trying to build *myproject* with `catkin_build`, and this second version of the g2o library. However, I see that `catkin_build` finds the first version of the g2o library, the one in the ROS workspace.

I have a *CMakeLists.txt* under the *myproject* directory and I tried different ways to specify the exact package location:

- First, I tried with:

`find_package(G2O REQUIRED PATHS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/g2o)`

In this case the error is the following:

```
CMake Error at /home/myproject/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "G2O" with any of
  the following names:

    G2OConfig.cmake
    g2o-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "G2O" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "G2O_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "G2O" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

- Then, I also tried with:

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/g2o/cmake_modules)
SET(G2O_ROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/g2o)
find_package(G2O REQUIRED)
```

And in this case the other g2o version was used.

Can you help me please?

**EDIT 1**

I think there is a related question on Stackoverflow:
[How to clone, build, and link g2o framework in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680427/how-to-clone-build-and-link-g2o-framework-in-c)
However I do not have the directory specified by `${CMAKE_PREFIX_INTALL}` in /home/user/ . I do not understand what I have to do...

**EDIT 2**

For building and installing the g2o library I launched the following commands in the g2o root directory:

- mkdir build
- cd build
- cmake ../
- make

Comment: If you have g2o library **installed**, then you should have `G2OConfig.cmake` file. If you don't have this file, then you need to **install** g2o.

Comment: If I launch the `make install` instruction I get this error `No rule to make target 'install'`. However, I see this "install" instruction in the CMakeLists file: `INSTALL(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/g2o/config.h DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/g2o)`. I do not see any `G2OConfig.cmake` file. Just a `config.h.in` file

Comment: Actually there is not the `G2OConfig.cmake` file even in the directory of the other g2o version.

Comment: File `G2OConfig.cmake` is installed by `install` with parameters `FILES "${G2O_PROJECT_CONFIG}" "${G2O_VERSION_CONFIG}"` ([CMakeLists.txt:407](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L407)).

Comment: So why there is not that file when I launch `make`?

Comment: Please, show your steps for building and installing g2o library.

Comment: I added **EDIT 2** to the question

Comment: `make` just **builds** the library. **Installation** is performed with `make install`.

Comment: If I launch the `make install` instruction I get this error `No rule to make target 'install'`.